# Exclude setter-only property from Add-Migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a model that contains a private setter-only property, which I would like to tell EF Core (2.1.0-preview2-final) to ignore when doing an `Add-Migration`, as such:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Prop { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    private string PropPrivateSetter
    {
        set { Prop = value; }
    }
}
```

My context uses the new `EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>.HasData()` method as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Model>(entity => entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Id }));
    // This line causes Add-Migration to fail.
    modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().HasData(new Model { Id = 1 });
}
```

When I run `Add-Migration`, I get the following error:

```
PM> Add-Migration MyMigration
System.ArgumentException: Property Get method was not found.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityType.GetData(Boolean providerValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateData(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetModel>b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_1(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalAccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Property Get method was not found.
PM>
```

I've tried calling `Ignore` before the `HasData` call, but to no avail:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Model>(entity => entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Id }));
    modelBuilder.Entity<Model>(entity => entity.Ignore("PropPrivateSetter"));
    // This line causes Add-Migration to fail.
    modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().HasData(new Model { Id = 1 });
}
```

Is there a way to do this without resorting to doing something like adding a `get { return null; }` to my property?

Comment: Why do you need such property? For what purpose?

Comment: It is working correctly for me in 2.1.0-preview2 (after adding Id property to Model class). Are you adding that property in the model explicitly somewhere?

Comment: @Smit I've enhanced my question as per your comment, and I found that calling `HasData` reproduces the problem.

Comment: @viveknuna It has to do with a UI issue.

Comment: @WhitneyKew - You hit a bug in EF Core. I have filed https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11858

Comment: @Smit - Thank you for looking into that and for filing a bug!